# Swift and Objective C: Project-Swift.h and Project-Bridging-Header.h conflict

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a project that intermingles Swift and Objective-C.

I'm currently trying to call a method from Swift, on a View Controller written in Objective-C.

To expose that method, I added the View Controller's header to the Bridging-Header.h file.

However, the View Controller references Project-Swift.h, which apparently 'does not exist' when the bridging header is being compiled. If I remove the inclusion of Project-Swift.h, the project compiles, however then I don't have access to the Swift functionality I need from the Objective-C end.

The exact error is:

```
"/Project/ViewController.h:10:9: error: 'Project-Swift.h' file not found
#import "Project-Swift.h"
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Project/Project-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I seem to have a chicken and egg problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Can I call an Objective-C method without including the bridging header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you include the `Project-Swift.h` file inside the `.m` file, so in `ViewController.m`. If you have any classes defined in there that you need in the header, just add forward class declarations with `@class MyClassFromProjectSwift`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Forward-declaring the classes works great (thanks!) however I'm having trouble forward-declaring protocols using this method. (For example, `@protocol SecondSwiftControllerDelegate;` yields the warning `Cannot find protocol definition`).

Comment: I was hoping you don't have protocols that you need in there, because sadly you can't forward declare those.
I would try to have this protocol declaration in ObjC instead. The thing is that with what you're trying to do you're causing a include-loop. The compiler needs the bridging header to be able to compile the Swift part and it needs to have the Swift part compiled to be able to get the protocol definition for the ObjC part.